# Пропуск фрагмента при хождении по back stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-back-stack

Имеется 3 фрагмента: A, B, C.

Все хостятся на одной `Activity`, из A вызываю B, потом из B вызываю C (A -> B -> C).

При нажатии кнопки "back" в фрагменте C нужно пропустить фрагмент B и вернуться сразу в A.

Искал инфу долго, либо постановка проблемы другая и решение не подходит, либо предлагают вызывать `popBackStack` два подряд раза, что, по моему мнению, ужасно, да и франмент B мне нужно пропустить именно программно, а не визуально, чтобы не заметил пользователь.

Код ниже.

**Фрагмент А**, вызов фрагмента B:

```
this.mFuelCardAuthBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainFragment.this.getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container, AuthProgressFragment.newInstance())
                    .addToBackStack(MainFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

**Фрагмент B**, вызов фрагмента C:

```
this.getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragment_container,
                            AuthSuccessFragment.newInstance(AppConst.FUEL_CARD_AUTH_TYPE))
                    .addToBackStack(AuthProgressFragment.class.getCanonicalName())
                    .commit();
```

**В Activity-хосте** обработка нажатия клавиши Back:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Вообще, есть ощущение, что обработка возврата по back у меня реализована не правильно, хоть и работает, поэтому буду признателен, если направите на правильный путь в этой теме.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно откатить транзакции до фрагмента с указанным тэгом:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(fragmentName, 0);
```

Т.е если в onBackPressed указать fragmentName равным тэгу фрамента А, то должен будет он показаться вместо B.

По идее костылём можно проверять кол-во фрагментов в менеджере и если их больше 2, то вызывать это, иначе super

Comment: хорошо было бы, если бы было так, только вот это не так и этот (самый очевидный и, по идее, правильный вариант) не работает, фрагмент B все равно вызывается. Возможно, дело в обработке события `onBackPressed` в Activity, поэтому и просил обратить на это внимание.

Comment: К тому же, если не добавлять фрагмент B в стек, то при нажатии кнопки Back в фрагменте B я выхожу из приложения, а мне нужно возвращаться в фрагмент A. Такая боль..

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy. Обновил ответ. Нужно А тоже с тегом добавлять и до этой транзакции откатываться если фрагментов в менеджере больше 2